# ATtiny13A cannot be programmed anymore with Arduino as ISP at 500 Hz

Tags: arduino, avr, avrdude, clock-speed, isp

My ATtiny13A fuses are set to use the internal 128 kHz clock without clock divided by 8.
I found online an ArduinoISP sketch that allows me to program it with that clock speed. But then I uploaded some code with those lines at the start of my `main()` to set the clock division factor to 256:

`CLKPR = (1 << CLKPCE);
CLKPR = (1 << CLKPS3);`

So my clock should normally now runs at 500 Hz. I guess it works, but I now cannot program my ATtiny13A anymore, it gives me unexpected signature error.

I found this ArduinoISP sketch online: https://github.com/lmpipaon/ArduinoISP_slow_SCK

Seems nice but it says it does not work with the 256 prescaler, which is what I need. When I try nevertheless to use the 256 prescaler with 600 baud rate in the ArduinoISP sketch, avrdude (`avrdude -b600 -cstk500v1 -P /dev/cu.wchusbserialfa130 -pattiny13 -e -U flash:w:lowVoltage.hex`) still gives me unexpected signature errors.

I also tried adding `-B 8000` or `-B 10000` with my upload command but apart from giving me different device signatures, it does not upload my code.

Comment: Holding the device in reset while powering it on will prevent the code from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Holding the device in reset while powering it on will prevent the code
> from running.
>
> – Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

It worked!